# Hide y axis below a certain x value when floating zero

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have data graphed in an xy scatter with straight lines and markers. Data are plotted at (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 0), and (4, 0). The last two data points are directly on the x axis. To fix this, I want the x axis to be slightly below y= 0.

Here's what I've tried:

Setting the min-y value to a negative number (e.g. -1). I then set the x axis to cross at a number greater than y = -1 (e.g. y= -.02). While this drops the x axis (i.e. floats the zero) as desired, the y axis and negative y-axis values up to -1 are shown on the graph. Typically to cover this area up, I add a white shape with no border. This is neither elegant nor works well when set up in VBA to be used with data sets of various sizes.

When I set the min value to y=-.02 and the x axis to cross at y= -.02, I don't have to worry about the negative values on the y-axis, but the major interval changes to .8, 1.8, 2.8, etc. If I wanted to change the major interval to 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, etc., I'd need to set the min value to -.5, which is far too large when I only want the data points to be slightly above y=0.

Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The regular axis formatting options won't do what you want to achieve, so you need a workaround. For example:

Hide the X axis altogether by formatting it to have no line. Use a new data series with two points. The first point is X=0, Y=-0.02, the second data point is x=the max of the other two series (formula) and Y is the same as the first data point.

Format this series as a line without markers and use it in lieu of the X axis. You can even make the position of this fake X axis dynamic by calculating the Y value from your data, if you want.

This will work with data from the grid, so you don't need to manipulate with VBA, but you could place the series with VBA instead, if you want.

If you need more help implementing this, leave a comment and I'll add more detail.